# How to create and drop tables in MySQL databse using Spring's NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbctemplate

I know how to insert, update and delete data in MySQL table using [`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html). But how to create and drop tables?

Comment: Read BalusC's comment to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/q/2101439/1401019

Comment: thanks..:) fully aware of the risk. just want to know if it's possible or not..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would create a table, or drop a table, the same way you execute a DML statement... SQL statement is passed as a string to the database engine.

I suspect what you are asking is if it's possible to supply an *identifier* (e.g. a table_name) in a SQL statement, by supplying it as a *value* for a bind placeholder in the execution of a prepared statement. e.g.

```
 CREATE TABLE ? (mycol INT)
```

or

```
 CREATE TABLE :my_table_name (mycol INT)
```

The short answer is that it's not possible to do that.

An *identifier* in the statement (for example a table name) must appear as in the SQL text. Just like the keywords `SELECT` and `FROM` must appear in the SQL text, and can't be supplied as value through bind placeholders.

We can demonstrate that restriction in a SELECT statement, attempting to supply the name of a table or view as a bind placeholder. It doesn't matter whether that's positional `?` or named placeholder.

This doesn't work:

```
SELECT t.col c FROM ? t LIMIT 1
```

And this doesn't work:

```
SELECT 2 AS :col_alias FROM :v_table_name LIMIT 1
```

This restriction regarding identifiers makes sense if you have an understanding of the operations that the SQL optimizer performs in preparing and executing a statement.

This restriction applies to SELECT statements. And to DML statements (INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE) and to DDL statements (CREATE,ALTER,DROP).

---

Another potential issue with executing a DDL statement will cause an implicit commit. We need to take care that to handle that correctly in the context of a transaction.

---

If you need to execute a dynamic DDL statement, supplying an identifier with a variable, there are two basic approaches:

1) dynamically constructing SQL text as a string so the table name (and other identifiers) are part of the SQL text, and not bind placeholders.

2) create a stored procedure that will perform the statement, and call the stored procedure. Arguments to the stored procedure can be passed as bind placeholders.